# Rename Multiple XML tags to different name

Tags: java, xml, xslt, transform

I am looking to transform tag to other format but it is transform only parent tags not child tags.
I want to transform the tag without change in the structure.

Eg:

```
<section name="ABC">
    <section name="123">
        <p>Data</p>
        <p>Data</p>
        <p>Data</p>
    </section>
    <section name="456">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Data</p></td>
                <td><p>Data</p></td>
                <td><p>Data</p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </section>
    <section name="232">
      <bold><p>Data</p></bold>
    </section>
</section>
```

to

```
<div class="ABC">
    <div class="123">
        <h1>Data</h1>
        <h1>Data</h1>
        <h1>Data</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="456">
        <table>
            <tr>
                    <td><h1>Data</h1></td>
                    <td><h1>Data</h1></td>
                    <td><h1>Data</h1></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="232">
        <bold><h1>Data</h1></bold>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what i have written in XSLT transformation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
        <xsl:template match="section"><div><xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/></div></xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="p"><p><xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/></p></xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="table"><table><xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/></table></xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="row"><tr><xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/></tr></xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="cell"><td><xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/></td></xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="image"><img><xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/></img></xsl:template>
        
        <xsl:template match="/">
              <html>
              <body>
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
              </body>
              </html>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Every thing is working fine but all attributes are getting timed i am getting only tags but not attribute values. I want to apply all attributes to be preserved and change  name of specific attribute alone.

Comment: So where does your attempt to use XSLT fail? Each of your requirements can be expressed literally as a template e.g. `<xsl:template match="section"><div><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></div></xsl:template>` implements your first requirement, use the same approach for the other requirements, use the identity transformation as the base template and the job is done.

Comment: Exactly XSLT is not working as expected and also tags re not getting nested.What if multiple sections are nested.

Comment: You haven't shown any attempt to solve that problem with XSLT and I have outlined a strategy to tackle any such basic transformation so give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do the Job:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="section"><div><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></div></xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p"><h1><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></h1></xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="table"><table><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></table></xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="row"><tr><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></tr></xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="cell"><td><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></td></xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="image"><img><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></img></xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@name"><xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute></xsl:template>
    <!-- identity transformation -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is really helpful. I have used the same syntax and i am able to generate output as expected.